# Linq to convert collection of objects with xml properties to collection of objects representing xml elements?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, linq-to-objects

I have an `IEnumerable<Item>` where Item has a property named "widgets" which contains xml as a string. The xml contains elements for each widget and each widget can contain an optional element named 'foo'. For example:

```
<widgets>
    <widget code="A">
        <foo>1</foo>
    </widget>
    <widget code="B" />
</widgets>
```

Can I flatten the `IEnumerable<Item>` into an IEnumerable of an anonymous type which represents a widget?

Comment: So, you're saying take every element of the `IEnumerable<Item>`, and return a new `IEnumerable<a'>` that contains all the `<widget />` elements from the XML as distinct items?

Comment: Yes, and ideally I'd also like a couple properties on the anonymous type to be populated from properties on the item.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `select new { ItemName = item.Name, WidgetCodes = widgetCodesFromXml, Foos = foosFromXml }`, where Widget and Foos are IEnumerable<string> containing the values retrieved from the Xml, or instead `select new { ItemName = item.Name, WidgetXmlElements = widgetXmlElements }`, where WidgetXmlElements are IEnumerable<XElement> derived from the widget elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `foo` can be repeating element or not, but in this case it's returned as an `Enumerable<String>`, which is simple enough to change.

The setup (here there are two items, with the same `Widgets` XML):

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name;
    public string Widgets;
}

var xml = "<widgets>\r\n    <widget code=\"A\">\r\n        <foo>1</foo>\r\n    </widget>\r\n    <widge" +
"t code=\"B\" />\r\n</widgets>";

var item1 = new Item {Name = "I1", Widgets = xml};
var item2 = new Item {Name = "I2", Widgets = xml};
var items = new Item[] {item1, item2}.AsEnumerable();
```

The widget selection process:

```
var widgets = 
    from item in items
    from widget in XElement.Parse(item.Widgets).Elements("widget")
    select new {
        Name = item.Name,
        Code = widget.Attribute("code").Value,
        Foo = widget.Elements("foo").Select(f => f.Value)
    };
```

That gives you 4 items (I1 A, I1 B, I2 A, I2 B) with Name (from Item) and Code and Foo (from the XML) set correctly.

If you want `foo` to be a single element, the change is as follows (setting `FirstOrDefault` basically), which will give you nulls for when `foo` isn't around:

```
var widgets = 
    from item in items
    from widget in XElement.Parse(item.Widgets).Elements("widget")
    select new {
        Name = item.Name,
        Code = widget.Attribute("code").Value,
        Foo = widget.Elements("foo").Select(f => f.Value).FirstOrDefault()
    };
```